# Is there a more idiomatic way to specialise behaviour using flags passed via template?

Tags: c++, templates, c++20

Apologises for the ambiguous title.

Here is my code:

```cpp
struct LowHigh
{
};
struct HighLow
{
};

template < class LookupScheme>
struct ladder_base
{
    using value_type     = price_depth;
    using ladder_type    = std::vector< value_type >;

    template < class T >
    struct lookup;

    template <>
    struct lookup< LowHigh >
    {
        static constexpr auto func = std::upper_bound< ladder_type::iterator, value_type >;
    };
    template <>
    struct lookup< HighLow >
    {
        static constexpr auto func = std::lower_bound< ladder_type::iterator, value_type >;
    };

    void
    insert(value_type v)
    {
        auto iter = lookup< LookupScheme >::func(std::begin(data_), std::end(data_), v);
        data_.insert(iter, std::move(v));
    }

  protected:
    std::vector< value_type > data_;
};
}   // namespace detail

struct bid_ladder : detail::ladder_base< detail::HighLow >
{
};

struct offer_ladder : detail::ladder_base< detail::LowHigh >
{
};
```

I'm specialising `lookup::func` depending on the scheme passed as a template type. There are currently only two possible schemes: `LowHigh` & `HighLow`. This has the effect of determining how the underlying vector is sorted.

Is there a more idiomatic/cleaner way to express this logic?

Comment: To add a tad more info - I'm ideally looking to remove the need to define and specialise a meta object, in this case `lookup`.

Comment: Seems like you could just pass the functors directly as the template parameters and bypass `LookupScheme` completely, this would be the same as the standard library containers/algorithms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These algorithms take a comparison object as their last parameter - so you can use that to your advantage.

```cpp
template < class Compare >
struct ladder_base
{
    using value_type     = price_depth;
    using ladder_type    = std::vector< value_type >;

    void
    insert(value_type v)
    {
        auto iter = std::upper_bound(data_.begin(), data_.end(), v, Compare{} );
        data_.insert(iter, std::move(v));
    }

  protected:
    std::vector< value_type > data_;
};
```

And then use `ladder_base<std::less<>>` or `ladder_base<std::greater<>>`, depending on which sort order you want.

---

Note that `std::lower_bound` and `std::upper_bound` are *not antonyms*, so your original wasn't really correct. `lower_bound` gives you the first element `>= x` and `upper_bound` gives you the first element `> x`. So changing from one to the other doesn't change your sort order (both require increasing order), only the comparison object affects that.

For instance:

```cpp
std::vector<int> v = {1, 3, 5, 7};
auto i = std::lower_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 3); // this is the 3
auto j = std::upper_bound(v.begin(), v.end(), 3); // this is the 5
```

Note that the vector is sorted in increasing order, but both calls are perfectly well-formed. If you wanted a reverse sort, you'd have to pass `std::greater{}` in as the comparison object (as I'm showing).

But either way, you want to use `std::upper_bound` - regardless of sort order.

Comment: Two birds with one stone. Could you explain why `std::lower_bound` shouldn't be used regardless?

Comment: @AlexHodges Makes more sense to insert after equivalent elements, not in front of. Moves fewer things. Both work though - but the important point is that the choice of algorithm is not a function of the comparison.

Answer (score 1):

The idiomatic way of doing that type of stuff is to have the template parameter contain the code to invoke directly, instead of indirecting through a tag type like you are doing.

Mind you, at that point, you could always just pass `std::upper_bound` directly as a template parameter.

Furthermore, since this is tagged `c++20`, you would also ideally use a concept, to constrain the types that can be passed to `ladder_base`.

```cpp
#include <concepts>
#include <vector>

using price_depth = int;

template<typename T>
concept LookupScheme = requires (const T& x, const std::vector<price_depth>& v) {
    {x(v.begin(), v.end(), price_depth{})} -> std::same_as<decltype(v.begin())>;
};

namespace detail {
struct LowHigh {
    template<typename ForwardIt, typename T>
    decltype(auto) operator()(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, const T& value ) const {
        return std::upper_bound(first, last, value);
    }
};

struct HighLow {
    template<typename ForwardIt, typename T>
    decltype(auto) operator()(ForwardIt first, ForwardIt last, const T& value ) const {
        return std::lower_bound(first, last, value);
    }
};

template <LookupScheme Scheme>
struct ladder_base
{
    using value_type     = price_depth;
    using ladder_type    = std::vector< value_type >;

    void insert(value_type v)
    {
        auto iter = Scheme::exec(std::begin(data_), std::end(data_), v);
        data_.insert(iter, std::move(v));
    }

  protected:
    std::vector< value_type > data_;
};

}   // namespace detail

struct bid_ladder : detail::ladder_base< detail::LowHigh >
{
};

struct offer_ladder : detail::ladder_base< detail::HighLow >
{
};
```

You can see the same approach used in the standard library's sorted containers, such a `std::map<>`'s `Compare` parameter.